# Create a dictionary with different length for values using dictionary comprehension

Tags: python, python-2.7

Here is the input string:

```
 visa = (u'GPIB0::5::INSTR', u'GPIB0::3::INSTR', u'ASRL1::INSTR', u'ASRL2::INSTR')
```

My code is a generator inside a dictionary comprehension, shown here:

```
  {comm : node for comm, node in (instance.split('::')[0:2] for instance in visa)}
```

Current Output:

```
{u'ASRL1': u'INSTR', u'ASRL2': u'INSTR', u'GPIB0': u'3'}
```

Desired output:

```
{'ASRL1': 'INSTR', 'ASRL2': 'INSTR', 'GPIB0': (5, 3)}
```

Any way to do it based on dictionary/generator approach?

Cheers,
I.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `defaultdict` for this:

```
>>> import collections
>>> d = collections.defaultdict(list)
>>> for item in visa:
...     comm, node = item.split('::')[0:2]
...     d[comm].append(node)
```

You can then convert it to your desired data structure as follows:

```
>>> {key: (value[0] if len(value) == 1 else tuple(value)) for key, value in d.items()}
{u'ASRL2': u'INSTR', u'ASRL1': u'INSTR', u'GPIB0': (u'5', u'3')}
```

Comment: It is a good one! But I was looking for a solution without importing other module. Just for the heck of it..:) How do you get rid of the unicode symbol (u)? Cheers!

Comment: @flamenco: you could call `str()` on each string to remove the Unicode symbol (in 2.7). However, that may not be the right thing to do.